# convert serve command to pm2 configuration file

Tags: reactjs, node.js, nginx, pm2

i use the following command to run the reactjs app (i use docker for nginx (172.18.0.199), 172.17.0.1 is the linux host itself)

```
pm2 serve -l tcp://172.17.0.1:3001 -n -s build --ssl-cert cert/cert.pem --ssl-key cert/key.pem
```

it works fine, but i want to make a config.js to run , here is the file

```
module.exports = {
  apps: [
    {
      name: "frontend",
      script: "/usr/bin/serve",
      args: [
        "-l tcp://172.17.0.1:3001 -n -s build --ssl-cert cert/cert.pem --ssl-key cert/key.pem"
      ],
      exec_mode: "fork_mode",
      error_file: "./logs/frontend-error.log",
      out_file: "./logs/frontend-out.log",
      instances: 1,
      autorestart: true,
      watch: false,
      max_memory_restart: "10G",
      env: {
        PM2_SERVE_SPA: "true",
      },
    },
  ],
};
```

when i check the pm2 logs

```
11|fronten | Exposing /home/ubuntu/src/mydomain/frontend/-c directory on 0.0.0.0:8080
11|fronten | Exposing /home/ubuntu/src/mydomain/frontend/-c directory on 0.0.0.0:8080
11|fronten | Exposing /home/ubuntu/src/mydomain/frontend/-c directory on 0.0.0.0:8080
11|fronten | Exposing /home/ubuntu/src/mydomain/frontend/-c directory on 0.0.0.0:8080
11|fronten | Exposing /home/ubuntu/src/mydomain/frontend/-l tcp:/172.17.0.1:3001 build --ssl-cert cert/cert.pem --ssl-key cert/key.pem directory on 0.0.0.0:8080
11|fronten | Exposing /home/ubuntu/src/mydomain/frontend/-l tcp:/172.17.0.1:3001 -n -s build --ssl-cert cert/cert.pem --ssl-key cert/key.pem directory on 0.0.0.0:8080
11|fronten | Exposing /home/ubuntu/src/mydomain/frontend/-l tcp:/172.17.0.1:3001 -n -s build --ssl-cert cert/cert.pem --ssl-key cert/key.pem directory on 0.0.0.0:8080
11|fronten | Exposing /home/ubuntu/src/mydomain/frontend/-l tcp:/172.17.0.1:3001 -n -s build --ssl-cert cert/cert.pem --ssl-key cert/key.pem directory on 0.0.0.0:8080
```

the nginx is also behind cloudflare, here is the config of nginx of my domain

server {
listen 80;
listen 443;
server_name mydomain.com;

```
ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/conf.d/cert.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/conf.d/key.pem;


location / {

    proxy_pass https://172.17.0.1:3001;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

}
```

}

can one know what is the problem?

Comment: Your args array contains one single space-separated string now. Did you try to break down each argument into separate array values?

Comment: Something like `[ "-l", "tcp://172.17.0.1:3001", "-n", "-s", "build", "--ssl-cert", "cert/cert.pem", "--ssl-key", "cert/key.pem"],`

Answer (score -1):

i've diff the difference between two process, for using config.js, i have to use interpreter instead, and use the path in script, and need to remove build in args

```
module.exports = {
  apps: [
    {
      name: "frontend",
      script: "/home/ubuntu/src/mydomain/frontend/build",
      interpreter: "serve",
      args: [
        "-l",
        "tcp://172.17.0.1:3001",
        "-n",
        "-s",
        "--ssl-cert",
        "cert/cert.pem",
        "--ssl-key",
        "cert/key.pem"
      ],
      exec_mode: "fork_mode",
      error_file: "./logs/frontend-error.log",
      out_file: "./logs/frontend-out.log",
      instances: 1,
      autorestart: true,
      watch: false,
      max_memory_restart: "10G",
      env: {
        PM2_SERVE_SPA: "true",
      },
    },
  ],
};
```